# How can I make nested string splits?

Tags: c#, string

I have what seemed at first to be a trivial problem but turned out to become something I can't figure out how to easily solve. I need to be able to store lists of items in a string. Then those items in turn *can* be a list, **or some other value that may contain my separator character**. I have two different methods that unpack the two different cases but I realized I need to encode the contained value from any separator characters used with string.Split.

*To illustrate the problem:*

```
string[] nested = { "mary;john;carl", "dog;cat;fish", "plainValue" }
string list = string.Join(";", nested);
string[] unnested = list.Split(';'); // EEK! returns 7 items, expected 3!
```

This would produce a list "mary;john;carl;dog;cat;fish;plainValue", a value I can't split to get the three original nested strings from. Indeed, instead of the three original strings, I'd get 7 strings on split and this approach thus doesn't work at all.

What I want is to allow the values in my string to be encoded so I can unpack/split the contents just the way before I packed/join them. **I assume I might need to go away from string.Split and string.Join and that is perfectly fine. I might just have overlooked some useful class or method.**

- How can I allow any string values to be packed / unpacked into lists?
  *I prefer neat, simple solutions over bulky if possible.*

---

*For the curious mind, I am making extensions for PlayerPrefs in Unity3D, and I can only work with ints, floats and strings. Thus I chose strings to be my data carrier. This is why I am making this nested list of strings.*

Comment: A lot of answers have been about simply replacing the separator character. This isn't really viable, it's too simple and too brittle. This won't easily allow "any" content in the list, nor will it handle deep nested lists well since you'd have to define a lot of special characters up front. So far, Base64 encoding has been the best candidate since it would remove the useage of separator characters for each item, encoding the values. I'd like to see if anyone could come up with a solution using escape characters or similar. Otherwise, the Base64 answer gets accepted as a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your strings with base64 encoding before joining.

Comment: This is a useful answer for my problem. +1. However, Base64 does consume a lot of space. I don't yet know if the extra consumption price is too large, but otherwise this is a candidate answer. You understood I need to encode the values so I can safely split/join. I'm thinking this could also be done with escaping characters somehow, but I can't wrap my head around that method.

Comment: I chose this answer because the implementation is quite trivial. A potential drawback I can see is it's inefficient when dealing with 1 MB worth of storage. @[Niklas Karlsson] posted another solution that also seems to work. I don't yet know if all the characters can be used on the storage medium (it's stored in registry values for example), but his approach seems to be the most memory effecient. Many people suggests to use another separator character and this can be sufficient for other peoples cases. I need my values to be able to contain any characters so I'm out of luck with those.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
const char joinChar = '╗'; // make char const
string[] nested = { "mary;john;carl", "dog;cat;fish", "plainValue" };
string list = string.Join(Convert.ToString(joinChar), nested);
string[] unnested = list.Split(joinChar); // eureka returns 3!
```

using an ascii character outside the normal 'set' allows you to join and split without ruining your logic that is separated on the `;` char.

Comment: This won't solve my problem as then I would not be able to use ╗ in my values. I want to escape the separators all together. Also, it would be a pain to create deeply nested items.

Comment: Statement, the ╗ was an example of a char outside the normal ascii keyboard range. use any char that you like. i think you'll need to make your question clearer as nearly every answer here has interpreted your requirement as this - you're a tough taskmaster :-)

Comment: I guess I could have been clearer but the question mentioned *"Then those items in turn can be a list, **or some other value that may contain my separator character**."*.

Comment: I'll make sure to rewrite the question once I get back home.

Comment: so, in effect. it's a kind of recursive list creation solution that's needed perhaps?? i'll have a wee think and get back in a bit

Comment: Exactly. I want to be able to store "any" string in each list item. It can be encoded/decoded, that's fine. That's what Base64 would do. I'm looking for ways to achieve this. While Base64 does so, I also know it expands the string a lot and I only need to escape the separator character for value items.

Comment: While I did accept an answer, I would be glad to reconsider it if you do come up with something after your wee think :)

Answer (score 1):

The expected items are 7 because you're splitting with a `;` char. I would suggest to change your code to:

```
string[] nested = { "mary;john;carl", "dog;cat;fish", "plainValue" }
string list = string.Join("@" nested);
string[] unnested = list.Split('@'); // 3 strings again
```

Comment: This won't solve my problem as then I would not be able to use @ in my values. I want to escape the separators all together. Also, it would be a pain to create deeply nested items.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a different separator, eg "|"?

This way the joined string will be "mary;john;carl|dog;cat;fish|plainValue" and when you call list.split("|"); it will return the three original strings

Comment: This won't solve my problem as then I would not be able to use | in my values. I want to escape the separators all together. Also, it would be a pain to create deeply nested items.

Answer (score 0):

Use some other value than semicolon `(;)` for joining. For example - you can use comma `(,)` and you will get `"mary;john;carl,dog;cat;fish,plainValue"`. When you again split it based on `(,)` as a separator, you should get back your original string value.

Comment: This won't solve my problem as then I would not be able to use , in my values. I want to escape the separators all together. Also, it would be a pain to create deeply nested items.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution of my own as well.

I could encode the length of an item, followed with the contents of an item. It would not use string.Split and string.Join at all, but it would solve my problem. The content would be untouched, and any content that need encoding could in turn use this encoding in its content space.

*To illustrate the format (constant length header):*

> < content length > < raw content >

*To illustrate the format (variable length header):*

> < content length > < header stop character > < raw content >

In the former, a fixed length of characters are used to describe the length of the contents. This could be plain text, hexadecimal, base64 or some other encoding.

*Example with 4 hexadecimals (ffff/65535 max length):*

> 0005Hello0005World

*In the latter example, we can reduce this to:*

> 5:Hello5:World

Then I could look for the first occurance of `:` and parse the length first, to extract the substring that follows. After that is the next item of the list.

*A nested example could look like:*

> e:5:Hello5:Worlda:2:Hi4:John

- (List - 14 charactes including headers)

  - Hello (5 characters)
  - World (5 characters)
- (List - 10 characters including headers)

  - Hi (2 characters)
  - John (4 characters)

A drawback is that it explicitly requires the length of all items, even if no "shared separator" character wouldn't been present (this solution use no separators if using fixed length header).

Answer (score 0):

Maby not as nice as you wanted. But here goes :)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] str = new string[] {"From;niklas;to;lasse", "another;day;at;work;", "Bobo;wants;candy"};
        string compiledString = GetAsString(str);
        string[] backAgain = BackToStringArray(compiledString);
    }

    public static string GetAsString(string[] strings)
    {
        string returnString = string.Empty;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                writer.Write(strings.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; ++i)
                {
                    writer.Write(strings[i]);
                }
            }
            ms.Flush();

            byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
            returnString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    public static string[] BackToStringArray(string encodedString)
    {
        string[] returnStrings = new string[0];
        byte[] toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedString);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(toBytes))
        {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                int numStrings = reader.ReadInt32();
                returnStrings = new string[numStrings];
                for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; ++i)
                {
                    returnStrings[i] = reader.ReadString();
                }
            }
        }
        return returnStrings;
    }
```

Comment: +1 (but I have to wait 14 more hours?). It does encode the values safely. This looks like a memory effecient solution to the one I posted. I actually did implement this but using string.SubString and hexadecimal length notation, length.ToString("X4").